# deconstructor is very lazy, why?

Tags: c++

What is really the destruction of the object?
If you do so:

```
class K {
public:
   K (int m) {v = m;}
   int v;
};


Class * x = reinterpret_cast <K*> (:: operator new (sizeof (K)));
new ((void *) x) K (2);


x-> ~ C ();
cout << x-> v; / / result: 2

:: operator delete ((void *) v);
```

Deconstructor did NOTHING! (?) Why?

Comment: **Undefined behaviour**... (besides: There is really nothing to be done when you only have to destruct a int..., the automatically generated destructor is probably completely empty)

Comment: This should be a compilation error; class `K` does not have a function `~C()`.   If you meant `~K()`, then the destructor call and deallocation are OK, but the behaviour is undefined to do `x->v` after calling the destructor. The default destructor is empty, so I'm not sure why you are surprised that it did nothing.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two sets of ideas that you are dealing with:

1. Construction and destruction of objects
2. Allocation and deallocation of memory.

It's important to understand how those can be properly combined.

Say you have a function:

```
void f1()
{
   // Construct an object.
   // The constructor gets called.
   K k(10);

   // Do something with the object.

   // Done with the function
   // The object k gets destructed.
   // The destructor gets called.
}
```

In this function you are constructing the object on the stack. When you return from the function, the destructor gets called automatically. Memory is allocated and deallocated from the stack automatically for you.

Now, let's look at another function.

```
void f2()
{
   // Allocate memory for the object.
   // Use that Construct an object .
   // The constructor gets called.
   K* k = new K(10);

   // Do something with the object.

   // Done with the function
   // Delete the object.
   // The destructor gets called.
   // Deallocate the memory.
   delete k;
}
```

This line `K* k = new K(10);` in this function performs two operations -- it allocates memory for the object from heap as well as calls the constructor to construct the object.

The line `delete k;` also combines two operations. It calls the destructor first and then it deallocates memory from heap. If you didn't have `delete k;`, the function will leak the memory allocated by `new K(10)`.

Here, we used the `new` and `delete` operators.

Now take look at using the global `operator new` and `operator delete` functions.

```
void f3()
{
   // Allocate memory for the object from the heap.
   void* p = ::operator new(sizeof(K));

   // At this point, an object of type K has not been constructed yet.

   K* k1 = reinterpret_cast<K*>(p);
   // Using the reinterpret_cast to treat the `void*` as a `K*` does not
   // change that fact. An object of type K has not yet been constructed still.

   K* k2 = new (p) K(10);
   // Use placement new operator to construct K.
   // At this point, an object of type K has been constructed by calling
   // K's constructor using the memory pointed to by p.


   // Do something with the object.

   // Done with the function.
   // Now it's time to do the necessary things to release resources back to
   // the system.

   // Do not use `delete K` at this point.
   // Whenever you use the placement new operator, call the destructor explicitly.
   // This calls the destructor ~K(), but does not deallocate memory from heap.
   k2->~K();

   // Deallocate the memory heap.
   ::operator delete(p);
}
```

Comment: If I ask of sth via mail?

Comment: Explain that, please.

Comment: In the near future I am going to instruct the Scheme, and would have him questions.

Comment: I'm guessing that English is your preferred language for communication!!! If I understand your comment correclty, you are saying that you are going to teach Scheme in the near future and that you would have more questions. And you would like to know whether you can ask me those questions via email. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49852/discussion-between-r-sahu-and-user3425832)

Answer (score 3):

What did you expect it to do (typos aside)? You have a POD type that does not need any destruction to happen. Try the same thing with something more meaty, say, put a `std::string` in there, and the destructor will actually do something.

Then, put those experiments aside and if at one place in the next twenty years you actually do need placement new and explicitly called destructors, put some debugging output in the destructor you need and check that it is actually called.

Answer (score 1):

> Deconstructor did NOTHING! (?) Why?

Because it is empty in this case. What did you expect it to do exactly?